# Find vertex at distance d

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I have a tree with N vertices. I want to design an algorithm to quickly answer some queries. Given vertex V and integer d, I want to find vertex at distance d from V. If there is more than one vertex at distance d then output any. I obviously know how to do brute-force. I also tried some idea similar to LCA finding algorithm (calculating ancestors at distance 1, 2, 4, 8...), but without any result.

I will have many queries, like 10^6, so I would like to answer them in O(1) or O(log N) time

Comment: To find a point in a given distance, you simply loop over all points and test them. For more complex queries - like k-nearest points and similar, use kd-tree, range tree or any other similar data structure.

Comment: Why didn't the LCA-like solution work?

Comment: Because it calculates distances to ancestors, but not to descendants.

Comment: Do you want an vertex that has any path of `d` edges between it and the root or do you want the minimum distance to be `d`? I.e. If there are the paths `a->b->c->d->e->f->g` and `a->g` then is vertex `g` a distance of `6` from vertex `a` or is it only a distance of `1` (or can it be both distances)?

Comment: @MT0 in a tree, the (simple) path between vertices is unique. So no such situation can occur

Comment: @NiklasB. Ah, yes. I missed that one very important word.

Answer (score 1):

This approach will work

1. Compute the centroid of the longest path in the tree. To do that, use depth-first search to find the vertex x where the max of vertex depths in the tree rooted at x is minimal
2. Compute the depth of all vertices in the tree rooted at x using a simple tree traversal
3. Group the queries by the index of the connected component into which their query would fall if x was removed
4. Iterate over all queries by component. Say your query is (v, d). If depth(v) <= d, then you can just use the d-th ancestor of v as the answer, using a [standard approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_ancestor_problem#Jump_pointer_algorithm) in O(log n). Otherwise, check if there is a solution vertex w with path(v, w) crossing x and dist(v, w) = d by looking up the depth d - depth(v) in one of the other components (e.g. in O(1) via hashing)

This works because if there is an answer for query (v, d) with depth(v) >= d, then there is a path of length d starting at v that crosses x, due to the property of x.

You can implement steps 1 and 2 using a single depth-first search.

For step 4, you want to keep a hash table that associates depth with vertices in a way that you can remove and add vertices in O(1). Then you can perform it in linear time when working component by component.

The total run time will be O((n + q) * log n).

This can be made online by precomputing the depth data structure from step 4 using persistent binary search trees, again in O(log n) per query.

Comment: After removing x, do I have to find centroids in the connected components?

Comment: @user128409235 After removing x, just apply the algorithm recursively to each connected component. So yes, that involves finding the centroid of each CC

Comment: Hm... wouldn't it be sufficient to just find centroid, create array of vertices vector<int>vertices[N], and store in vertices[1] vertices at distance 1, vertices[2] store at distance 2 etc. and also longest path from centroid and then answer every querry in O(1)?

Comment: @user128409235 I think you're right, actually we don't need recursion. However, we need to chose a slightly different x for this to work (see edit). And we need to handle the case where for a query (v, d), depth(v) <= d, i.e. the answer is the d-th ancestor. That can be done in O(1), but it's complicated. O(log n) is much simpler

Answer (score 0):

Add a weight to each edge of the tree corresponding to the number of descendants. This can be done only once and is O(*N*)

If you only want to find a vertex at specific distance *d* you can do so in O(*d*) steps by simply walking the tree up and eventually down, as soon as you find a branch with a high enough weight to get to *d* steps.

If you are doing many queries on the same tree, this will perform very well.

Comment: It's really easy to design a class of inputs where your proposed algorithm will have run time Omega(q*n) where q is the number of queries. For example, what if the tree is just a path of length n and all the queries are on one of the end points?

Comment: In that case each query would take O(d) not O(N). the only case in which we need to go through the whole tree is when *d* = *N*

Comment: Yeah, so each query is (1, N - 1) and you have edges 1 - 2 - 3 - ... - N

Comment: @NiklasB. Can you explain yourself better? What does "each query is (1,N)" mean? there are *N* elements in the tree, *q* queries, each with a specific distance *d* (which is less than or equal to N). This algorithm performs as O(q * d) which is less than or equal to O(q * N).

Comment: sure, but OP wanted an O(N  + q) or O((N + q) log N) algorithm. Just pointing out that this approach here has worst-case Ω(N) time *per query*

Comment: @NiklasB.I see that as O(N) for each query, it doesn't make any sense to ask otherwise (surely you need to address each query at least once!)

Comment: Well but it's surely possible that you can solve a query for example in O(log N) time after some preprocessing of time O(N log N) or less. That's what data structures are for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101282/discussion-between-sklivvz-and-niklas-b).

Answer (score 0):

While building graph/addling links, for given node
you can store map of edges for that Vertex, where distance is key and edges at that distance as value. This way you can build and retrieve in O(1)

```
class Vertex{
  String vertexLabel;
  Map<Integer,List<Edge> edgeMap;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Run the Floyd–Warshall algorithm once one one your graph to compute the shortest path between all pairs, then use this ?
Maybe just a depth-first-search starting from V and stopping at depth d would be enough, depending on how many queries you intend to perform.

Comment: It is a brute-force algorithm, and I am looking for O(n) or O(n log n)

Comment: depth-first-search will be O(n) (and likely less depending on d), since all vertices are visited at most once.